# submodule couldn't import parentmodule (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, git-submodules

These are the directories of my module:

```
mymodule
|-__init__.py
|-file1.py
|-file2.py
|-test
  |-__init__.py
  |-test_file1.py
  |-test_file2.py
```

`test_file1.py` contains this command: `from .. import file1`.

---

To run the tests I did this (on the command line): `python3 -m unittest test.test_file1`. (When I ran that command for the whole `test` directory it just told me "everything is fine" but didn't find my tests.)

The answer (also in the command line, of course) was (without a huge part of the stacktrace):

```
   File "/media/me/my_usb/backup me/myfolder/django projects/django-mymodule/mymodule/test/test_file1.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .. import file1
ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package
```

What to do to fix this? What's best-practice with tests in multiple files?

---

**Edit:**
I tried a few things as suggested, and that's what I have done:

1. I changed the tests direction (as suggested in the *Hitchhikers guide to python*. That's what it looks now:

   ```
   modulewrapper
   |-mymodule (with the 2 files in it)
   |-... (docs, readME and this stuff)
   |-tests
     |-test_file1.py
     |-test_file2.py
   ```
2. I imported `mymodule` after inserting the direction like this (I added this code in the beginning of every test file):

   ```
   import sys
   sys.path.insert(0, '../mymodule')
   import file1
   ```

---

I started the test as usual: `python3 -m unittest test_file1` from the tests directory.
What now happened is this: (first the relevant part of the stacktrace, then my guess):

```
File "/media/me/my usb/backup me/my folder/django projects/django-mymodule/tests/test_file1.py", line 4, in <module>
    import file1
  File "../mymodule/file1.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .file2 import MyClass1, MyClass2
SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import
```

How to deal with that new problem? (or is it the same as before? It seems hardly to be a kind of best_practice to change working code to be able to run tests.)

---

**Edit2:** For now, I jusr replaced `from .file2 import someclass` by `from file2 import someclass`. Can this have any negative side effects?

Comment: `test` is your top-level package. You can't go outside that for relative imports. Either run `mymodule.test.test_file1` or add `mymodule` to your Python path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the module `test.test_file1`, `test` is your top-level package. You can't go outside that for relative imports; you can only reach other modules *within* the `test` package.

Either run `python3 -m unittest mymodule.test.test_file1` (with your working directory set to the parent directory of `mymodule`) or add `mymodule` to your Python path and use `from mymodule import file1`.

Generally, best practice is to put a `tests` *directory* next to your project:

```
mymodule
|-__init__.py
|-file1.py
|-file2.py
tests
|-test_file1.py
|-test_file2.py
```

Note that there is no `__init__.py` file, but some test runners (specifically `pytest`, may require one).

This is how the Django project itself organises tests, as do most other Python projects (see, for example, [`click`](https://github.com/pallets/click), [`requests`](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests) or [`flake8`](https://github.com/PyCQA/flake8)). Use a test runner to discover tests, like `nose`.

You'd need to add your `mymodule` parent directory to the Python path for this to work, of course, so you may want to add

```
import os
import sys
here = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.dirname(here))
```

to the top of your test files, or to put that into a `utils.py` file you put in your tests directory.

Also see the [*Structure* section of the Hitchhikers Guide to Python](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/structure/).

Comment: How do these test runners work? Have I to write them? (How?) And where to store them? (I guess, also in the tests module.) | And the thing about `here` - this is part of the test I'm running, isn't it? So how do I import another directy by importing the directory where I am? (I didn't really understand the last path, because I never used python tests except the normal django way to do it.)

Comment: @Asqiir: The `unittest` module is such a runner. `setup.py` can also discover tests, as can the `nose` and `pytest` projects.

Comment: @Asqiir: `manage.py test` also uses the `unittest` as a test runner. I think it does want the tests to live inside the package however.